# Runtime Error 15 - Type Mismatch for code to change a password in MS Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I get a Runtime Error 15 on the following line:

`MyuserID = Me.txtfirstname.Value` from the code below:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdchange_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Trim(Me.txtnewpass & "") <> Trim(Me.txtconfirmpass & "") Then
    MsgBox "Passwords do not match", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, ""
    Me.cmdchange.Enabled = False
    Else
    Me.cmdchange.Enabled = True
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select' From[User Registration Details] where [UserID]=" & MyuserID)
    If Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF Then
        rs.Edit
        rs("Password") = txtconfirmpass
        rs.Update
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        MsgBox "Your Password has been successfully changed", vbInformation, "Electporl"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmnewpassword", acSaveNo
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmlogin"
      End If
    End If
```

Given that I placed the code below on the button that takes the user to the changing password form.

```
Private Sub cmdproceed_Click()
       If IsNull(Me.txtfirstname) Or Me.txtfirstname = "" Then
       Me.mand1.Visible = True
       Me.txtfirstname.SetFocus
    End If
      If IsNull(Me.txtemail) Or Me.txtemail = "" Then
      Me.mand2.Visible = True
      Me.txtemail.SetFocus
    End If
      Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("User Registration Details", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    rs.FindFirst ("Firstname='" & Nz(Me.txtfirstname, "") & "'")

    If rs.NoMatch = True Then
        Me.lbl1.Visible = True
        Me.txtfirstname.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If rs!Username <> Nz(Me.txtemail, "") Then
        Me.lbl2.Visible = True
        Me.txtemail.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'MyuserID is publicly declared as Long in a module
    MyuserID = Me.txtfirstname.Value
    DoCmd.OpenForm " frmnewpassword"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End Sub
```

the second code is assigned to the button that redirects the user to the form that will enable him or her change the password after verifying his or her first name and email.

The second one now is assigned to the button that will help the user change the password by overwriting the old password.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: well when i click on the proceed button i get a runtime error 15 saying Type Mismatch and the line "MyuserID = Me.txtfirstname.Value" is highlighted. i am no able to figure out what is wrong. help me please.

Comment: Is txtfirstname a string? Sounds like a string, and you can't store a string in a long.

Comment: The error message here should be telling you everything you need to know in order to fix the issue. You have a type mismatch, so the type of data you are trying to store in a variable is not compatible with the type you declared the variable as.

Answer (score -1):

Please pass the `UserID` value in your procedure.

In your `cmdproceed_Click()` procedure update the following section:

```
'MyuserID is publicly declared as Long in a module
MyuserID = rs("UserID")
```

In your `cmdchange_Click()` procedure update the following line:

```
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From [User Registration Details] where [UserID]=" & MyuserID)
```

From a logical point of view, you can have others with the same `firstname`, so doing the filter on the `firstname` only will introduce unexpected behaviors later in the life cycle of your application.

If you have two or more users with the first name 'Joshua' then your code will always select the first user with that first name. You need to update this logic to select a unique user.